# Generate a week view calendar with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

Im trying to generate a week view calendar using codeigniter's calendar library.. something like this

[image]

how can i do that? :/ 
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the UI with the help of Javascript libraries such as [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Otherwise, you'd have to manually generate the table, with as many `<tr>`s as the time intervals you want in a day. Plus, you won't have interactivity unless you write the AJAX parts yourself. So, you're better off using existing js libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Calendar template, look at the bottom of this page http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html